# C#, Visual Studio 2015,

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am in Germany at Alfatraining to learn C#.
I had no Problem until Friday ??? Everything worked fine.
On Friday - presentation day - it didn't work ???

Path Definition:

```
 private static readonly string accessDbPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(
              Application.StartupPath, @"..\..\..", "DB",  "KundeArtikel.accdb"));

private static readonly string connectionString =
            "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" +
            "DBQ=" + accessDbPath;
```

*until* Thursday everything allright:

> C:\Users\Alfa\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Main Program\Main Program\DB\KundeArtikel.accdb

**after** Friday:

> C:\Users\Alfa\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DB\KundeArtikel.accdb

Does anyone know, what changes were made. Program is the same.
I assume changes were made within 
*Extras\option* or 
**Project-Explorer**.

Comment: Welcome to programmers world. On presentation day - it never works :)

Comment: Don't you think you should ask this on MSDN/Visual Studio discussion? They could help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I programmed the program in DEBUG State X86.

The presentation I presented in RELEASE State X64.

The Output Path changes automatically from "bin\x86\Debug\" TO "\DB".

(ProgrammExplorer MainProgram Properties).

Comment: There is no automatation that will change the output path to "\DB". You have changed the release path some days before, but you never noticed because of debug mode. Create a plain new project and check the default output path for release/debug x86/x64

Answer (score -1):

Thank you Sir Rufo, 
you are right. 
I created a new project and the default were there. 
I am "rookie" in C#. 
I didn't know the meaning of properties. So I definetely called it up and changed anything. 
I complaint about the tutor. 
(No Linq, no ADO, no Debugging, ...  within 6 weeks ???)
Maybe that was my mistake.
Now I know the meaning of "output path".
Thanks all. Problem solved.